# R: changing color of stacked barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

```
library(ggplot2)
df2 <- data.frame(supp=rep(c("VC", "OJ"), each=3),
                dose=rep(c("D0.5", "D1", "D2"),2),
                len=c(6.8, 15, 33, 4.2, 10, 29.5))
head(df2)
ggplot(data=df2, aes(x=dose, y=len, fill=supp)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]

I have a simple stacked barplot, and I would like to change the colors manually. More specifically, I would like to flip the colors used for `fill = supp` (i.e. teal for OJ instead). I've trid adding a `color = ...` parameter into `geom_bar` but that simply outlines the barplots instead of coloring them in.

Comment: You want to add `+ scale_fill_manual(values = c("green", "violet"))` to the end of your code as shown to add your own colors (notice this is **FILL**, not **COLOR**). However, to keep those fill colors and just flip them, use `+ scale_fill_hue(direction = -1)`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
ggplot(data=df2, aes(x=dose, y=len, fill=supp)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+scale_fill_manual(values = c("Green","tomato"))
```

[image: green and tomato colours added]

Comment: I have multiple stacks and I want to change colors too but not manually. Is it possible?

Comment: yes it is possible, you can choose color platelet.