# Change the order of Stacked Bars within a given chart in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've been struggling for a while now to change the order of stacked bars within a given chart.

I did find several other topics talking about the order of stacked bar plots with ggplot2, however none answered my specific question. ([How to change stacking order in stacked bar chart in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33538059/how-to-change-stacking-order-in-stacked-bar-chart-in-r), [How to control ordering of stacked bar chart using identity on ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32345923/how-to-control-ordering-of-stacked-bar-chart-using-identity-on-ggplot2), [R: changing color of stacked barplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43721603/r-changing-color-of-stacked-barplot))

Here is some reproducible data to illustrate my issue :

```
df <- data.frame("Gene" = 1:300, "A" = runif(300), "B" = runif(300), "C" = runif(300))
```

Now let's order the dataframe by the maximum value of A,B or C.

```
max.var <- pmax(df$A, df$B, df$C)
df <- df[order(max.var, decreasing=T),]
head(df)

Gene         A         B         C
290 0.1843646 0.9998304 0.4633329
86 0.2595463 0.9977324 0.3269114
18 0.9959791 0.0368044 0.9469783
238 0.9944759 0.5037651 0.6842606
260 0.4355420 0.4844317 0.9934755
3 0.3702984 0.9922708 0.4254061
```

Finally let's order it so it creates 3 different groups : a first one regrouping all situations where A is higher than B and C, a second one for situations where B is higher than A and C, and a last one for C higher than A and B.

```
max.var <- pmax(df$A, df$B, df$C)
df.ordered <- rbind(df[which(df$A==max.var),], df[which(df$B==max.var),], df[which(df$C==max.var),])
head(df.ordered)

Gene         A         B         C
18 0.9959791 0.0368044 0.9469783
238 0.9944759 0.5037651 0.6842606
235 0.9857518 0.2102292 0.6547545
121 0.9809101 0.5440542 0.4712545
73 0.9791348 0.4560130 0.3859089
252 0.9677200 0.3219051 0.5486373
```

Now to plot that as a stacked bar plots, let's format the data:

```
df.Toplot <- data.frame("Value" = c(df.ordered$A, df.ordered$B, df.ordered$C), "Var" = factor(rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each=nrow(df)), levels=c("C", "B", "A")), "Gene" = factor(rep(df.ordered$Gene, 3), levels=df.ordered$Gene))
Plot <- ggplot(data=df.Toplot, aes(x=Gene, y=Value, fill=Var)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
print(Plot)
```

This bit of code gives me something that groups Genes according to their maximum value (between A, B and C):
[image: Example1]

Here we have three groups that we can easily identify as (i) A>(B or C), (ii) B>(A or C) and (iii) C>(A or B). The first group looks fine, but I would like the two other groups to look like it, meaning that the first bar in genes from group B gives the value of B, and in genes from group C the first bar gives the value of C.

I know I could make three separate plots, but my end goal is to do a circular bar plot, and I don't see how I could do that with three different plots.

Circular plot:

```
Plot2 <- ggplot(data=df.Toplot, aes(x=Gene, y=Value, fill=Var)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + coord_polar(start = 0)
print(Plot2)
```

[image: ExampleCircularBarPlot]

I would really appreciate any help, let me know if anything is unclear, this is my first time asking a question here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I follow, but is this what you're looking for?

```
Plot <- ggplot(data=df.Toplot, aes(x=Gene, y=Value, fill=Var, group = Value)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
print(Plot)
```

[image]

Comment: It is! I can't believe it was so easy. Thank you (for the answer, and for editing my post)!